# Confused about the change in to notation when performing vector addition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am watching the 3Blue1Brown video series on linear algebra and I have run into some confusion while watching this video at the [6:52](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs)
minute mark.

In this section of the video, it is stated that the like terms from each vector are matched together and their sum is subsequently taken. However, while matching the terms, the notation of vector $x_{2}$ changes to $y_{1}$ and $y_{1}$ to $x_{2}$.

[Please refer to this link to see what I am confused about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUG7O.png)

Can someone explain, why the change in the notation occurs?

Cheers!

Comment: What video is it at least?

Comment: Apologies. I have made changes to the post. You can now refer to the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3B1B notes in a pinned comment that he made a mistake:

> Thank you to everyone who pointed out the typo at 6:53, where the component-wise sum should of course be [x1+x2, y1+y2].

> In general, little mistakes in videos like this will be mentioned in the video description.

Or, to use the notation from the video, it should be

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ y_1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}x_2 \\ y_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 + x_2 \\ y_1 + y_2\end{bmatrix}$$

The confusion probably came because it's typical when writing the components of a vector to keep the main variable the same and vary the subscripts, so for example $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ instead of $v_1 = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I must have gone momentarily blind because I completely missed that comment.